# Concurrency in Sqoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, sqoop

I have read documents where it is recommended to install sqoop on edgenode for many reasons which is understood and for every mapper a connection to source database is established. My question is will all the 4 connections be established from edgenode or sqoop-client in edgenode just creates some kind of driver which monitors the ingestion while datanodes connect to the databases,get the data(part) and split it locally and then put in HDFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqoop is a wrapper over Map reduce to perform import export operation.

1. Mappers will run in your cluster , while the sqoop client will run the edge node.
2. Each mapper will open a connection to your database.
3. What rows are consumed by your mapper are decided by the client when submitting the job.

Comment: By default 4 mappers will run right and consider i have a 6 node cluster where one is NN,one Edgenode and 4 datanodes so when a sqoop job is fired will the 4 datanodes connect to database or edgenode will spwan 4 threads,get the data,split it and put in hdfs?

Comment: Sqoop is MapReduce based framework,  sqoop client will  run on edgenode, The Map jobs wil run on the DataNodes .  The mapper will connect to database. 

The number of mapper spawned is based on the inputFormat and in case of sqoop it is DBInputFormat

Answer (score 0):

Edge node acts as an interface to Hadoop cluster, sqoop import/export launches the MapReduce job based on the generic and specific arguments.

MapReduce job runs the number of mappers based on the -m or --num-mappers argument given.

For Detailed information see below links:
http://www.dummies.com/programming/big-data/hadoop/edge-nodes-in-hadoop-clusters/

https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#id1764013